# Python list generate ascending order

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
  List1 = ['ab_01:2,20,100', 'ab_02:1,300,10', "ab_03:5,400,22","ab_04:8,5050,22"]
```

I have list how to make it in ascending order. Only check after colon value (in this case 2,1,5,8) to decide ordering  and keep all values as it is.

Expected Output:

```
   List1 = ['ab_02:1,300,10', 'ab_01:2,20,100', "ab_03:5,400,22","ab_04:8,5050,22"]
```

If it is only numeric then  I could have to use sorted(list1, key=int).

The reason why i want this is, I want to iterate from  lower value in for loop.

Code I tried and struck in middle to proceed..

```
List2 = []
for x in List1:
    a = x.split(":")[0].split(",")[0]
    List2.append(a)
sorted(List2, key=int)
```

Comment: What've you tried?

Comment: the elements in your output don't match the ones in your input

Comment: the 1 in 'ab_02:1,300,10' becomes 2 in 'ab_02:2,300,10'

Comment: @Primusa, sorry i edited

Comment: @Sagar you still haven't provided us with what you have tried. SO isn't a code writing service. Show your effort and you will get help faster.

Comment: @MooingRawr and coldspeed, I have tried for loop and splited : and again splited with , separated and taken value to another list..This way i got all values in one list. and I have used sorted(list1, key=int). In this case values are miss matching

Comment: The purpose is to show your effort in your post so we can correct what you have done/make suggestion if we see you are going down the wrong path. Edit your post with your effort with proper format.

Comment: @MooingRawr, I have edited post and efforts code i have appended

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
sorted(List1, key=lambda x: x.split(':')[1])
```

Comment: a/ please don't encourage/enable low effort posts, b/ your code doesn't cover all the possible cases it breaks on certain inputs

Comment: What inputs will it break on? When a ":" character doesn't exist?